# <div> whose size overflows its parent but respects the padding of its parent's parent

Tags: css

My page has a structure like

```
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        Some text
        <div class="inner">
            More text
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The outer `<div>` is sized using `max-width`, and I would like the inner `<div>` to have a width of 150%, so it pokes out of its parent to the right. However, if the browser window is narrow, then I want to clamp the inner `<div>`'s width so that it still obeys the padding on the `<body>` element.

The following snippet achieves my desired behavior:

- When the browser is very wide, the orange box is 150% the size of the aquamarine box.
- When the browser is somewhat narrower, the orange box shrinks so that its right edge is 100px from the right edge of the browser window. (Note that this 100px matches the 100px padding of the body.)
- When the browser is very narrow, so that the aquamarine box extends all the way to the right edge, the orange box also extends all the way to the right edge.

However, I find my solution inadequate because it relies on a manual calculation that depends on the padding, border, and margin settings of the `<body>` and outer `<div>` elements. It therefore very hard to maintain. **Is there a way to simply tell the inner `<div>` "overflow, but obey the padding settings on the `<body>` element"?**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.outer {
  padding: 80px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.inner {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 150%;
  /*
            max-width = (viewport width)
                        - 2 * (body padding)
                        - 1 * (.outer border)
                        - 1 * (.outer padding)
    
            I'm trying to avoid this manual calculation
            */
  max-width: calc(100vw - 290px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer">
    This element has a max width of 600px.
    <div class="inner">
      This element should be 150% the width of its parent, unless doing so causes it to overflow, in which case it should be as big as possible while still obeying the padding on the body. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, aperiam
      excepturi accusantium neque dolores consequatur hic repellendus doloribus inventore dolore fugit ipsum minima nostrum rerum. Id possimus voluptates ipsam rem.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try using margin on the children vs padding on the parent

Comment: For some reason, the SO format checker will not accept my snippet—it keeps telling me "your post contains code that is not formatted as code." Can someone with more privileges please fix override the formatter for me?

Comment: Please read the rest of my post and let me know what I can clarify.